# Pythonic way to check if values are present in a dict

Tags: python

I want to validate if there is a truth value present in a dictionary's values. If I validate the dict like below code then it says values exist as it would return `dict_values([''])`, which indicates in python that it's not None but if you'll check the dict then there is no value:

```
a = {1:''}
if a.values():
    print(a.values())
else:
    print('No values')
```

What's the best pythonic way to validate if a dict contains values or not? There can be cases where many keys are present but each has empty values.

Note:

- empty string would not be considered as a value (invalid, if condition would fail in this case).
- 0 would be considered as a valid value.
- the value would not be a list/dict/tuple, it can be either string, int or float

Comment: `all(a.values())` or `any(a.values())`?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I dont think so, if the int 0 is in there all() would return false, but it would still be valid!

Comment: @LukasNeumann *would* that be valid? It's not clear to me from the question exactly what the rules of validity are.

Comment: @jonrsharpe yes, the question is not clear.

Comment: The question is simple : if any value is present then it would pass the 'if' condition otherwise not. The value can be anything string/int/float/boolean etc.

Comment: You say that, but in your example there *is* a value. An empty string is still a value. `{}` would be a dictionary with no values. So the rules must be a bit more than that.

Comment: If any value is present, is not very clear to a programmer. What do you do with a `None` value, Pass or not? How do you want the integer `0` to be handled? What are all the possible value types you can get, `str`, `int`, `float`, `dicts`, `tuples`?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I have made changes to the question, is it clear now?

Comment: `all(is_valid(value) for value in a.values())`, then `is_valid` can apply whatever rules you want.

Comment: Unless you are specifically asking about how to solve a cross-version compatibility problem (in which case your question should obviously describe that problem) you should not mix the [tag:python-2.7] and [tag:python-3.x] tags. I have removed them both.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like all the usual falsey values are invalid, apart from numeric types of zero being valid. If this is the case, you can use [Python's Truth Value Testing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing) along with the [numbers module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/numbers.html#numbers.Number) from Python's standard library.

**Simple solution:**

This solution iterates over the dictionary's values twice.

*Returns `False` if there is one or more invalid values.*

```py
from numbers import Number

a = {1: "", 2: 0, 3: 0.0}
all(isinstance(x, Number) or x for x in a.values())  # False

a = {1: "Hello", 2: 0, 3: 0.0}
all(isinstance(x, Number) or x for x in a.values())  # True
```

**Better performance:**

Here `is_valid` will only iterate until the first invalid value.

```py
from numbers import Number

def _invalid(value):
    return not isinstance(value, Number) and not value

def is_valid(dict_):
    return next(filter(_invalid, dict_.values()), True)
```

**Alt**:

*Returns `True` if there is one or more valid values.*

```py
next(filter(lambda x: isinstance(x, Number) or bool(x), a.values()), False)
```

Comment: From other comments by OP it looks like those all's should be any's (or I'm misinterpreting their comments) but otherwise, this is probably the most elegant solution. Although I guess just checking the truth-value of str(x) might work as well for what was described.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`if a.values() and '' not in a.values():`

I'm not sure this is the best pythonic way, but it is simple and it works.